# Vuex - WebSocket events handling

Tags: vue.js, websocket, vuex

I have a WebSocket server that I handle in my vue/vuex client application with native websockets (no external library).

In my vuex modules, I can define `actions` to send WebSocket requests

```js
const actions = 
{
   sendMessage (context) 
   {
      context.rootState.socket.send("Some request")

      context.rootState.socket.onmessage = ({data}) => 
      {
         console.log("Data recieved " + data)
      }

      context.rootState.socket.onerror = () => 
      {
         console.log("Some error")
      }
   },
}
```

Here in my `sendMessage` `action`, I handle requests and also events. I want to know if there is a way to handle events properly, not inside of an `action`?

The problem is that I have to retrieve information about the socket somewhere, which is defined in my `rootState` so it's accessible for all modules.

Comment: It's unclear to me what your question is. If you want to handle events outside of the action you can create a separate singleton class (`sockets.js`) and do the sockets communication through there, and then have that class update the vuex state.

Comment: Yes, but how do I fire the events inside `sockets.js` from my components ?

Comment: by importing the class and executing functions from inside it